# After rotating to landscape and pressed home button and then restart the UI broken

Tags: ios, user-interface

I am trying to handle it with:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {

           if shouldRotate {
             return .LandscapeLeft
           } else{
             return .Portrait
           }

        }
```

But, when View controller change from Portrait to landscape. I press Home button and Restart the App, the UI Broken every time I press Back button.

Please help!

Comment: did you use constrains ?

Comment: Yes, I am using constraints in landscaping and portrait mode as well

Comment: UI works well, but when i press home button and open the app, UI distort. Any one here to help?